# RestKit IOS SSL certificate invalid

Tags: ios, ssl, glassfish, restkit

I installed a GoDaddy issued certificate and getting this error below while calling https with 8181 port. It worked fine with HTTP.

The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “my.ip.” which could put your confidential information at risk."

Did restkit error out because i am using IP instead of valid domain name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are connecting via typing https://your.ip:8181/ in your browser, that is the issue.
SSL/TLS certificate for web site contains domain name for which it is issued, and it should match the name typed in address bar.